# Android Studio - Importing Launcher Assets only Updates ic_launcher-playstore.png and the launcher icons under mipmap folders get deleted

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, android-icons

I am using Android Studio version 4.2.1.

I have the regular android resource structure with the app icon residing in the mipmap folders.

[image]

I am doing the following steps to change the app icon.

I add an image asset by right clicking the res folder -> Going to "New" -> "Image Asset"
[image]

I select the foreground image and then click "Next"

After than I see the following screen.
[image]

When I click "Finish" all of the icons in the mipmap folders get deleted and I am unable to build the app as my xml layouts have some references to the launcher icons and they are being deleted by this import process. This didn't happen before to me only happening with Android Studio version 4.2.1

Comment: I've also seen this. I find that if I run it twice, the first time will remove all the images (like shown in the picture with all the red filenames), and the second time it will add them back. Pretty annoying to have to run this twice, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to import an image asset by changing the name from `ic_launcher` to  a different name and then deleting the old launcher icon manually through "Finder" on mac, and renaming the new images to ic_launcher. To me, it seems to be a bug in Android Studio 4.2.1.